# Chef, File does not exists after force the creation

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have the following logic in a recipe that creates a file if it's missing and then tries to insert some lines in it.

```
file "/root/myfile" do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '400'
  action :create_if_missing
end

file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('/root/myfile') 

data_bag('my_databag').each do |user|

  # ... lines using Chef resources like user, group, etc.

  if node.chef_environment != "my_env"
    line = "something to write in myfile"
    Chef::Log.info("-----> #{line}") 
    file.insert_line_if_no_match(/#{line}/, line)
  end
end

file.write_file
```

The recipe fails in the case `myfile` doesn't exist despite I'm forcing the creation of the file before the instruction that causes the exception. So here is the error:

```
ArgumentError
-------------
File '/root/.testfile' does not exist

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
 18:
 19>> file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('/root/.testfile')
 20:
```

Can anyone help me to understand why this doesn't work? Any help on this would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I tried to touch the file first but still failing in the same line:

```
 26:  FileUtils.touch('/root/myfile')
 27>> file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('/root/.testfile')
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with chef, but it is possible that the `FileEdit` needs a file to exist before it can edit it? Try touching the file first to make sure it is actually there. `require 'fileutils'` and `FileUtils.touch('/root/myfile')`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this way but I'm currently using a Chef resource 'file' to create the file if it's missing but doesn't seem to create it before reaches the break instruction.

Comment: Tried adding 'FileUtils.touch('/root/myfile')', as you said, before Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('/root/.testfile') instruction but still fails in the same line.

Comment: Tried finally a sentence that worked: File.open("/root/.testfile", 'a') before edit the file. But not getting why other way doesn't work

Comment: Yeah like I said, I'm not familiar with chef so I just took a shot in the dark. If you find a solution that works for you, you can add it as an answer here and accept it in case someone else comes across this question in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is yet another issue of the two phase nature of chef.  Pure ruby code runs in the first pass.  This is the "compile" or "resource gathering" phase.  The ruby code for the chef resources just adds a resource definition to a list of resources.  After that is complete, then the second "execution" phase happens.  This phase will actually execute the resources.  So your `file` declaration doesn't actually do anything until after your FileUtils code fails.

Two things you could do:

First, you REALLY should avoid using FileUtils in your recipe if at all possible.  It would be far better to create your file with a template if you can.

Second, if you change your file declaration a little, you can hack it to run during the first phase:
xz

```rb
file "/root/myfile" do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '400'
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:create_if_missing)
```